# Store a value from a database into a variable for use outside of a "while" in PHP

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

This is the relevant bit of my code:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
            $pro_no = $row1['project_no'];
```

So outside of this "WHILE" i want to use $pro_no. How do i go about doing this?

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks, didn't realise i would not need a while loop

Comment: I am sure you just want only specific project no, right?

Comment: Yes, but the SELECT query will only return 1 result - the right one

Comment: If it returns only one result then not need to while loop simply do $row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1); $pro_no=$row1['project_no'];

Comment: If the select only returns one result you don't need a whileloop at all, just use mysql_fetch_array by itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one row you can do

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1));
$pro_no = $row1['project_no'];
```

or if you have mamy rows you can accumulate values in an array

```
$pro_no = array();
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
   $pro_no[] = $row1['project_no'];
}
```

At the end of while all the values from column `project_no` will be in your array

Answer (score 0):

After the loop it will be filled with the last value from inside the loop. Therefore it makes sense to set it to a default value to make sure it ran trough the while().

Example:

```
$pro_no = 'DEFAULT VALUE';
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $pro_no = $row1['project_no'];
}
var_dump($pro_no);


// shorter and faster way of finding the last value:
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
rsort($row1);
var_dump($row1[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're problem is that the value of $pro_no changes for each loop and you only reach the last one after the loop. Save them to an array instead to be able to use all later:

```
$pro_no[] = $row['project_no'];
```

Hope I understood the problem correctly

Answer (score 0):

Since $proj_no will change each time the loop runs, you need to assign the values to an array, and access the array.

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $proj_array[] = $pro_no = $row1['project_no'];
```